# How to migrate a datawindow from PB 10.5 to PB 6.5?

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

Is it possible to import a datawindow implemented in Powerbuilder 10.5 to Powerbuilder 6.5?

What changes have to be made in the export code?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an abbreviated export of a PB 6 datawindow.  Compare the properties of the columns and the datawindow itself to those of 10.5 and remove any not in the 6.5 version.

```
HA$PBExportHeader$d_mr_trs_approved_trs.srd
$PBExportComments$Datastore:  Info for print/fax from approved transcriptions
release 6;
datawindow(units=0 timer_interval=0 color=12632256 processing=0 print.documentname="" print.orientation = 0 print.margin.left = 110 print.margin.right = 110 print.margin.top = 96 print.margin.bottom = 96 print.paper.source = 0 print.paper.size = 0 print.prompt=no print.buttons=no print.preview.buttons=no )
summary(height=0 color="536870912" )
footer(height=0 color="536870912" )
detail(height=148 color="536870912" )
table(column=(type=long update=yes updatewhereclause=yes identity=yes name=vst_int_id dbname="vst_int_id" )
 retrieve="SELECT VISIT.vst_int_id
FROM   VISIT (NOLOCK)
,      TRANSCRIPTION_DTL (NOLOCK)
,      TRANSCRIPTION_HDR (NOLOCK)
,      TRANSCRIPTION_RPT_TYP (NOLOCK)

WHERE  VISIT.vst_int_id = ...

" arguments=(("al_trs_int_id", numberlist),("al_status", numberlist)) )
column(band=detail id=10 alignment="0" tabsequence=32766 border="0" color="0" x="2985" y="8" height="56" width="160" format="[general]"  name=pat_ty edit.limit=0 edit.case=any edit.autoselect=yes  font.face="Arial" font.height="-8" font.weight="400"  font.family="2" font.pitch="2" font.charset="0" background.mode="1" background.color="553648127" )

htmltable(border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" generatecss="no" nowrap="yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

First change the first line to 'release 6' and chop down the second line until it only contains color and processing.

```
release 6;
datawindow( color=16777215 processing=1 )
```

Then go to the bottom of the file and delete any lines that start with html or xml.

This should take care of most of the items. Try an import and fix any errors it finds. Repeat until it imports clean.

Comment: I have done all these but without success. Moreover, PB6 doesn't report any errors found.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to conver a DW from 12.5 to 10.5 thus I made this changes
in adition to the Roland Smith answer(that it was greate start):

-Change the release number.

-Change datawindow line like Roland says ('datawindow( color=16777215 processing=1)')

-You need to drop all 'transparency' and 'gradient' properties of every line, almost all lines of the DW like this ('gradient.color=8421504' OR 'header.transparency="0"')

-Drop the property 'enable="0"' in every computer field that you find it

And that's it.